# Chief factors of a group, are they always normal in G.

Tags: group-theory

Chief factors of a solvable group G, are they always normal in G?
I know Chief factors are characteristically simple. Also, characteristic subgroups are normal in G. So I think Chief factors are normal in G.
But I found an example, 1,V4,A4,S4 chief series, where Z2 is a chief factor, which is not normal in S4. Now I am confused.Please clarify this.

Comment: First: you probably mean "the factors that conform" a chief factor, as a chief factor itself is not even a subset of $\;G\;$, not to mention a subgroup or normal. Second, if you meant the above then, **by definition**, the answer is yes, as chief factors are formed from **normal** series, meaning each of the elements in the series is a *normal* subgroup of the big group. Do you have any other definition of "chief factor"? BTW, the group being solvable is irrelevant in this.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for the comment. Yes, chef factors are the quotients of the chief series. it is a subnormal series where series has no refinements without representation. But, what about the example for S4?

Comment: Well, in **my** definition, the chief factors are formed by the elements of a *chief series*, which is a **normal**, not *subnormal*,  series. You can check this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_series , or here: https://books.google.co.il/books?id=DPHMUeM_F2kC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=Chief+series+of+a+group&source=bl&ots=b63zJaSwHp&sig=F1-ADC9LLTlK2-nld8LssKTEfAo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS-5S6yOfSAhUL1RQKHdsPAhY4ChDoAQguMAY#v=onepage&q=Chief%20series%20of%20a%20group&f=false , or here: http://www.ms.uky.edu/~jack/2008-03-05-ChiefFactors.pdf

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. it should be a normal series. But, still I have the confusion with the above example. weather chief factors are normal in G

Comment: Look, your question does not make sense. Only a subgroup of $G$ can be normal in $G$ or not normal in $G$, and the chief factors are not subgroups of $G$, they are quotient groups of subgroups,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your example is

$$1\lhd C_2\lhd V_4\lhd A_4\lhd G$$

But this is **not** a normal series since, as you mentioned, $\;C_2\rlap{\;\,/}\lhd S_4\;$ and thus we have no chief factors here.

Where we do have a *normal series* is with

$$1\lhd V_4\lhd A_4\lhd S_4\;\;\;(**)$$

and for this to be a **chief series** it must be that every factor has no subfactor **that is normal in** $\;S_4\;$ ...and this is true! The only non-trivial factor a quotient in the above series has is $\;C_2\lhd V_4\;$,  but since $\;C_2\;$ is not normal in $\;S_4\;$ we don't care, and thus $\;(**)\;$ is a *chief series* ...

Comment: Thank you very much. which means, Chief factors need not to be normal in the whole group.

Comment: It doesn't mean that. The statement "Chief factors need not to be normal in the whole group." does not make sense, because chief factors of a group are not subgroups of the group.

Comment: @student Read the comment by Derek, which is the same I wrote in my first comment below your question: chief factors are different *sets*, let alone groups, than the whole group. In the above answer, $(**)$ is a chief **series** ( the elements of which are normal subgroups of $\;G=S_4\;$) , and the chief **factors** there are $\;V_4/1\cong V_4\,,\,\,A_4/V_4\cong C_3\,,\,\,S_4/A_4\cong C_2\;$ , which are *not even subsets* of $\;S_4\;$ ...

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @student Any time.